# How do I use remote debugging & browser sync

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, browser-sync

I have browser-sync running on `http://localhost:3000/`.  I also have chrome dev tools remote debugging enabled.

My problem is that on my mobile if I try to go to `http://localhost:3000/` tab then it is obviously unavailable.

How do I make it so I can view the development site on the connected mobile?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it's still interesting for you since your question was old.

If you have your development site on http://localhost:3000/, you should see Browsersync Control Panel at this address

http://localhost:3001/

Typing that url you will see under "Overview" menu a section called "External" with the external IP to use with other devices (assuming of course you are sharing same connecction, i.e, an internal wifi)

Try using that IP, that should work.

Answer (score 0):

You're using your phone to access your site, but the site itself is not hosted on your phone, so going to `localhost:3000` won't work.

If you're on a unix system you can type in `ifconfig` in your terminal to get your host's local IP address. For windows systems, the command is `ipconfig`.

You will probably find your local IP address under `en1` under the `inet` field. For example, mine is `10.0.1.9` so I would visit `10.0.1.9:3000` on my mobile device to view a website hosted on that computer.

Keep in mind that both your computer and mobile device must be connected to the same local network.

Comment: Remote debugging can pipe the local server to attached device according to docs but I can't figure it out.  (it's going over usb not local network)